# How to make self extracting exe using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to make a self extracting exe(abcdInstaller.exe), which runs another exe(AppInstaller.apk, this is installing abcd.apk on my pc). Below script works fine but when I run abcdInstaller.exe, it also extracts these two files on current directory(from where I'm running this exe) and runs the AppInstaller.exe.

But What I want, User just click on abcdInstaller.exe and abcdInstaller.exe will run AppInstaller.exe in background, which will do its work.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh


SilentInstall silent
RequestExecutionLevel user ;no elevation needed for this test
ShowInstDetails hide

# this will be the created executable archive
OutFile "abcdInstaller.exe"

InstallDir $EXEDIR

# the executable part
Section

# define the output path for the following files
SetOutPath $INSTDIR

# define what to install and place it in the output path...
# ...app...
File AppInstaller.exe
# ...and the library.
File abcd.apk

# run application
ExecShell "open" "AppInstaller.exe"

# done
SectionEnd
```

I tried to comment SetOutPath $INSTDIR, but then nothing happens.

Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $PluginsDir for files that are temporarily used during the installation:

```
SilentInstall silent
RequestExecutionLevel user
OutFile "Test.exe"

Section
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File "MyApp.exe"
ExecWait '"$PluginsDir\MyApp.exe"' ; Double quotes on the path

SetOutPath $Temp ; SetOutPath locks the directory and we don't want to lock $PluginsDir
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm updating my solution.

I'm copying the exe to temp folder and deleting the folder once I'm done with the process.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh


SilentInstall silent
RequestExecutionLevel user ;no elevation needed for this test
ShowInstDetails hide

# this will be the created executable archive
OutFile "ABCD.exe"

InstallDir $EXEDIR


# the executable part
Section

# define the output path for the following files
SetOutPath $TEMP\ApkPath

# define what to install and place it in the output path...
# ...your app...
File AppInstaller.exe
# ...and the library.
File xyz.apk

# run your application
ExecWait "$TEMP\ApkPath\AppInstaller.exe"

SetOutPath $TEMP

RMDir /r $TEMP\ApkPath

# done
SectionEnd
```